# Prevent Office 2013 from creating "Custom Office Templates" directory in My Documents

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

Office 2013 keeps creating the directory `C:\Users\user\Documents\Custom Office Templates`. I like to keep My Documents tidy for quick access.

Is there anyway to prevent Office from continually re-creating the `Custom Office Templates` directory after I remove it? Moving it somewhere else would work too. I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: This isn't really a solution, but behavior like this from many applications lead me to put the "My Documents" folder on a network share and mount it as read only. I keep a second, writable mountpoint for when I need write access. It's inconvenient, but highly satisfying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the answer to the question [Custom Template location in Office 2013](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/custom-template-location-in-office-2013/3820f370-b780-4679-a463-98fa44506e0b) on the Microsoft Community forums:

> You can choose to override this setting by specifying a Personal Templates Folder.  This can be done by going to File > Options > Save and manually entering a folder path.  This needs to be done for each application, and for any application that does not have a Personal Templates path manually set, Office will create the Custom Office Templates folder the first time you save a template, and will set the Personal Templates path to this location.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The original answer wasn't clear but it's specifically called `Default personal template location` in the Save options.

Comment: I use Office 2013 but I don't use templates, and this folder location was created for me anyway, even though I never saved any custom templates. My default personal template location search path is empty. I don't mind having an empty folder there. I always leave the Documents or My Documents folder for various applications to use and save my important documents elsewhere. They always clutter up this location so I stopped caring and trying to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Hide the folder under properties. You won't be able to see it but MS Office and Windows can still access it.

- Right-click on the directory
- Select "Properties"
- Check the "Hidden" checkbox under "Attributes"

Comment: How does one do this?  I personally know how to do it but the author of the question or other people with similar problems might not know.  I could  provided this information myself but would rather give you a chance to provide it.

Answer (score -1):

I was plagued by this problems for months - constantly deleting "Custom Office Templates" from My Documents only to have the pesky SOB pop up again. Finally I found the solution - when "Custom Office Templates" shows up in your Documents, right click on it, and choose Properties. Click on "Hidden" and voila!!

Comment: But hiding it isn't the same as deleting it.

Comment: This is identical to [Ryan's answer](https://superuser.com/a/986088/358766)